# Odd code being injected into WordPress site except when logged in

Tags: wordpress, security, code-injection

I'm working on a website that was previously hacked and thought I had cleared everything out of it, but recently it started loading extremely slow (~7 seconds) without touching anything. What makes it really weird is **if I'm logged into my admin account, the site loads fine and the code below isn't injected**.

After digging through a bunch of stuff, I came across this code being injected and can't track down where its coming from. Not sure if its related to the slow load time, but its messing up the styling all over my site:

```
<div id="top_bar">
    <p class="mob_phone">
        <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>
        <a href="mailto:...">...</a>

        <!-- weird code starts here -->
        <meta charset="EUC-JP">
        <title>404 File Not Found</title>
        <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright XSERVER Inc.">
        <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ...
        </style>
    </p>
    ...
```

**What I've Tried**

- I've disabled all my plugins and it still shows.
- I've done a Sublime Find search in the theme and child theme directories and didn't find any of that code
- I've Googled the name XSERVER but didn't find anything helpful
- Searched a database dump

If anybody recognizes it and can point me to how I can remove it, or has any other ideas on how to track down whats injecting it, it would be greatly appreciated! I'm running out of ideas

Comment: Have you searched a database dump for XSERVER, EUC-JP?

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo Gave it a shot, unfortunately it didn't find either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the Japanese version of wordpress. Please see here for reference - https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_install_auto_word.php&prev=search

I would recommend uploading the core files from the English site - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/download/

This should solve your problems.
It might be worth checking what theme you're using as well and seeing if it's a Japanese theme.

Comment: Interesting...I uploaded the files from the English version but it did not get rid of the code or speed my site up.

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to your website?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to share the link